# place query result in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

is there a way to set the autocomplete results with my own?
I know that  the JQuery.autocomplete  does this,  but  I was just  wondering if there was a different way to do this.

[image]

I've been so far just creating a div below everything, but was  wondering if it was possible apart from the  JQuery tools.

[image]

Comment: Well I'm not sure, but I think you would need jquery and ajax to implement something similar to google suggestions.

Comment: I agree. Jquery isn't bad,and most available plugins for autosuggestion use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typeahead.js is a fast and fully-featured autocomplete library

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JSBin with the basic code

http://jsbin.com/nalome/4/edit

You'd have to find an api for create an indexed database to search.

I did this once, using a similar idea to what you are doing. I had to fake all the form elements, making them divs, and appending a div below it like you are.  I then took over the the keys up/down/tab/enter so that you could navigate it the way you would expect to.  If you are asking if there is some native way that you can handle this, there isn't anything that I know of.

Backbone was a great help for this, since you could tie the click events to a restful api (if that's what you're using.) So that it searches the database on key stroke, and it also knows what you select when you choose a suggestion.